# RecyclerView - How to update adapter data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In `ScheduleAdapter`, I display a list that has the ability to expand/collapse a row. In the `ViewHolder`, `imgToggle.setOnClickListener(...)` handles the click event.  This is working fine.

The issue is when I scroll through the list, rows farther down the list (which are not visible initially) are automatically expanded.  For example, if I click on the first item in the list, the row expands.  As I scroll through the list, row six, (an arbitrary row: not visible at first) is expanded (it should not be).

I understand what the RecyclerView is doing.  Just not sure how to handle it?

In my code, I tried using `scheduleDetailVisibility` to manage the expand/collaspe behavior.  This approach is not working.

Another approach I could take is to add a property to my `ScheduleTrip` that could manage whether the *current row* is expanded/collapsed.  How would I update `schedules` so the adapter is aware of the change?

```
public class ScheduleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ScheduleAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<ScheduleTrip> schedules;
    private int rowLayout;
    private Context mContext;

    public ScheduleAdapter(ArrayList<ScheduleTrip> schedules, int rowLayout, Context context) {
        this.schedules = schedules;
        this.rowLayout = rowLayout;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(rowLayout, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v, mContext);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

        ScheduleTrip schedule = schedules.get(i);
        viewHolder.textViewRoute.setText(schedule.trip_id);
        viewHolder.textViewTripHeadsign.setText(schedule.trip_name);
        viewHolder.tableTimes.removeAllViews();
        viewHolder.tableTimes.addView(buildTable(schedule.departure_time, i));
        viewHolder.scheduleDetail.setVisibility(viewHolder.scheduleDetailVisibility);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return schedules == null ? 0 : schedules.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public View view;

        public TextView textViewRoute;
        public TextView textViewTripHeadsign;
        public ImageView imgToggle;
        public int scheduleDetailVisibility = View.GONE;
        public LinearLayout scheduleDetail;
        public LinearLayout tableTimes;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView, final Context context) {
            super(itemView);

            scheduleDetailVisibility = View.GONE;
            textViewRoute = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRoute);
            textViewTripHeadsign = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTripHeadsign);
            tableTimes = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tableTimes);
            scheduleDetail = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.scheduleDetail);
            imgToggle = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgToggle);
            imgToggle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int visibility = scheduleDetail.getVisibility();
                    switch (visibility){
                        case View.GONE:
                        case View.INVISIBLE:
                            scheduleDetail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            scheduleDetailVisibility = View.VISIBLE;
                            imgToggle.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_collapse));
                            break;
                        default:
                            scheduleDetail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            scheduleDetailVisibility = View.GONE;
                            imgToggle.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_expand));
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public ViewHolder(View itemView, final Context context) {
            super(itemView);

            scheduleDetailVisibility = View.GONE;
            textViewRoute = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRoute);
            textViewTripHeadsign = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTripHeadsign);
            tableTimes = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tableTimes);
            scheduleDetail = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.scheduleDetail);
            imgToggle = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgToggle);

            if (scheduleDetail.getTag()!=null){
                if(((Boolean) scheduleDetail .getTag())){
                    scheduleDetail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }else{
                    scheduleDetail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

            }else{
                scheduleDetail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            imgToggle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int visibility = scheduleDetail.getVisibility();
                    switch (visibility){
                        case View.INVISIBLE:

            case View.GONE:
                            scheduleDetail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            scheduleDetailVisibility = View.VISIBLE;
                            imgToggle.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_collapse));
scheduleDetail.setTag(true);
                            break;
                        default:
                            scheduleDetail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            scheduleDetailVisibility = View.GONE;
                            imgToggle.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_expand));
scheduleDetail.setTag(false);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: sorry #Steve, i'm just did an edition about the answer, check it.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have solved your problem. By the way  one thing I can say to you  that it can me  more easy and  controllable if you make changes  to Adapter level instead of struggling with View.Visibility of items while implementing Expandable list view using RecyclerView.
What I will  suggest you is , when click on sopme expandable item, just add new items at appropriate postion and use **RecyclerView.OnItemInserted(**) api.  Similary for collapsing list Item.Just remove items from main data list of  adapter and call **recyclerView.OnItemRangeRemoved(int intpos, int itemcount).**
I have implemented  this for a Retail app's categoryActivity inwhich some categories  are expandable.
One more advantage of this is  these api of  RV have its own animation or you can customize  the animation for in and out of items, which gives better user experience and also better performance.